# Dynamically add elements to output$ in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The following code works, but assignment is not dynamic:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  basicPage(
    actionButton("test", "Click"),
    textOutput("a"),
    textOutput("b")
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    output$a <<- renderPrint("a")

    i <- "b"
    output[[i]] <<- renderPrint(i)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

But if I have multiple items to add to `output` and their values can change, how can I dynamically create them?

I have tried:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  someinput <- letters[1:2]
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    # attempt 1
    # l <- lapply(someinput, renderPrint)
    # output <<- c(output, l)
    
    # attempt 2
    # for (i in someinput) {
    #   output[[i]] <<- renderPrint(i)
    # }
  })
}
```

Neither attempt works though. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this inline with what you're trying to do?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  someinput <- letters[1:2]

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    lapply(someinput, function(inp) {
      output[[inp]] = renderPrint(inp)
    })
  })
}
```

Not sure what your end goal is but you could also use `purrr::imap` to map the input name and then pass in values associated with each input into the reactive func.

```
library(purrr)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  someinput <- list(
    a = "a text",
    b = "b text"
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    imap(someinput, function(vals, nm) {
      output[[nm]] = renderPrint(vals)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am trying to do. Do you mind elaborating a bit more? How does assignment work within a list iteration? Do you know why the `for` loop in my example only returns that last value (`"b"` in my example)?

Comment: Sure thing, to my understanding the `renderPrint()` functions evaluate after `observeEvent()` is finished. In the for loop, `i` acts as a global variable where its final value is  `"b"`. So when it's time for the renderPrint to execute, they evaluate with "b".  Whereas in `lapply`, the context or environment is contained so the value of `inp` is preserved in each iteration and thus the `textOutputs` yield the expected values.

Comment: Ah okay interesting -- that makes sense. Wonder if then that can be controlled wit hthe `handler.env` argument of `observeEvent`. Appreciate the response!